# Android - bitmap resolution loss

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

Compared with the bitmap getting from `res/drawable`, the quality of the same bitmap getting from `intent` is much lower.

Since the current project is really concerned about the image quality, I want to get the original bitmaps (without compression or resolution loss) from phone storage.

So, how can I get the high quality bitmap from `intent`?

I use `intent` to get a bitmap from the external storage in this way,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button galleryBtn = new Button(getActivity());
    galleryBtn.setText("Import Photo...");
    galleryBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    });

    //... some more code here
}

//... some more code here

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 0)
        try {
            if (data != null) {
                InputStream stream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getData());
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stream.close();

                imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And I get the bitmap from `res` in this way,

```
imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: getData returns a thumbnail, you need to get the Uri from the intent with `getDataString()` then get the imave via the Uri

Comment: @tyczj: Huh? `data.getData()` returns the `Uri` to the piece of content chosen via `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.

Comment: "the quality of the same bitmap getting from intent is much lower" -- AFAIK, both code paths are going through the same image-decoding logic. Please edit your question and link to some bitmap that is giving you this effect, along with links to screenshots showing the results of using the resource and using the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`-delivered `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I drew some lines on both bitmaps (one getting from `intent`, another one from `res/drawable`, which are the same JPEG file), and I found that the bitmap getting from `intent` has thicker lines than the one getting from `res/drawable`. That's why I claimed that their resolution are different.

Comment: That could be a question of how they are being rendered, which `drawable/` resource folder you are using, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Intent has size limit to pass intent, So you can use public static object to do pass bitmap from service to broadcast

```
public class ImageBox {
    public static Queue<Bitmap> mQ = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Bitmap>(); 
}
```

pass in service,

```
private void downloadFile(final String url){
        mExecutorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap b = BitmapFromURL.getBitmapFromURL(url);
                synchronized (this){
                    TaskCount--;
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_ON_GET_IMAGE);
                ImageBox.mQ.offer(b);
                sendBroadcast(i);
                if(TaskCount<=0)stopSelf();
            }
        });
}
```

BroadcastReceiver,

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver get broadcast");

            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (DownLoadImageService.ACTION_ON_GET_IMAGE.equals(action)) {
                Bitmap b = ImageBox.mQ.poll();
                if(b==null)return;
                if(mListener!=null)mListener.OnGetImage(b);
            }
        }
};
```

It should work for you.
Let me know if any other help required.

Answer (score -1):

try this in you onActivityResult,

```
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
                cursor.close();
```

Comment: This will only work if the `Uri` happens to be one that came from the `MediaStore`, and then only if the `MediaStore` has a path, and *then* only if the path is a place where the app has read access (e.g., not removable storage).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but in order to get images from gallery the app will need to have read access to storage, right?

Comment: The app needs `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. That does not cover removable storage. A `Uri` obtained and used from the `MediaStore` relies on the *`MediaStore`* having access to the removable storage, which it does, courtesy of the device manufacturer. In your case, you are bypassing that, and the app will not have access to the removable storage (on Android 4.4+).

Comment: But I'm using this code to read images stored in removable storage (e.g., sd cards) and it is working in Android 4.4+

Comment: If `imagePath` points to removable storage, you will not have access to it, unless it is your own app's portion of removable storage (e.g., `getExternalFilesDirs()`), or your device does not comply with Google's Compatibility Definition Document.

Comment: It has been tested in several devices (including some nexus) so I don't think it has a problem the GCDD. @Tim could you give a try to what I suggested?

Comment: Nexus devices do not have removable storage, other than USB OTG drives.

Comment: I know they doesn't I refer to nexus for the comply you where saying. Like I said before it has been tested in several devices that uses removable storage and it is working fine.